# .Net MAUI - Admin Privileges on Windows

Tags: .net, manifest, .net-6.0, maui

Using .Net MAUI in Visual studio preview i am unable to run things that require administrator privileges for a Windows application.

I have tried the following:

- Open Visual studio preview as an administrator
- Setup app.manifest and .csproj with the following:

##### app.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

##### .csproj

```
<ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
```

I have a very similar WPF application, that also runs in .net 6 where admin privileges works if you run Visual studio as an administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track but you need another ingredient. Open the `package.appxmanifest` file with a text editor and make sure that the `Capabilities` node looks like this

```xml
<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation" />
  </Capabilities>
```

I've added the `allowElevation` one.

Then in your `app.manifest` add this part right under the `assembly` node

```xml
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
```

You can tweak the level as needed. It seems that if you set the `uiAccess` to true that is not supported. Also, elevation is only available from WinAppSdk 1.1+ and on:

- Windows 11 - May 10, 2022—KB5013943 (OS Build 22000.675)
- Windows 10 - May 10, 2022—KB5013942 (OS Builds 19042.1706, 19043.1706, and 19044.1706)

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/stable-channel#elevation

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, after updating windows and editing the `package.appxmanifest`  file it worked :)